# Are there any limitations with Visual Studio Setup Projects?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation, windows-installer

Are there any limitations that I might face when using VS Setup Projects?
I plan to use them, but am not sure if this would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in a more advanced setting: VS Setup Projects cannot be automated, e.g. you cannot put your project and the VS Setup Project on a build server and have them built automatically. This might not be an issue for a smaller shop or a single developer, but for a larger enterprise-level development environment, this alone can be quite a killer criteria.

In order to get around this, we use WiX for our setups - more work once up front, but works nicely with continuous integration.

Marc

Comment: I understand that devenv.exe is required to build the setup project. That means, you need to install visual studio on the build server. That does not seem to be a good idea but still it could be automated. You can run devenv using msbuild. Could not understand the statement "VS Setup Projects cannot be automated". Please help.

Comment: @anand patel: you're saying it yourself - in order to build VS Setup Projects, you'd have to install a full Visual Studio on your build server, and that's definitely *not* a good idea -> therefore, you cannot really automate VS Setup Projects (there's no MSBuild task not using Visual Studio to build VS Setup Projects)

Answer (score 2):

They are OK, if your starting from scratch I would say look into WIX, or even pony up the cash for Install Shield or one of the other commercial ones, would save you time and money in the long run.

Builds can be very slow, especially if you have a lot of binary files.  I have a project with a lot of product images that get packed into the install package, this takes a LONG time, even on a fast machine.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Setup projects lacks a number of key features that Windows Installer Provides. Most notable of these is the 'Feature' feature that allows you to setup several tools that the user can choose to install or exclude. As already recommended, use WiX or a 3rd party full-featured installer tool.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project I suppose. It used to be a pain to use to set up web projects, but I think there is an addin now that makes creating a web app setup a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

More limitations...

- There is no way in setup project to perform validation on data that has
  been provided by the user on the UI dialogs (acquisition phase).
- There is no way to designate a custom action to run with elevated
  privileges(System account).
- There is no way to make your custom action execute during UI sequence.

Comment: Is it not the case that all custom actions run in deferred mode, system context in Visual Studio Installer Projects? I am testing with 2017. Maybe it has changed.